# PHP error handling and sending form data to e-mail

Tags: php, forms, validation

What will be the best PHP validation code for this: If error array is empty and either e-mail or phone is provided then send the email and go to confirmation page?

Below is the code and it is not working. Once the form is submitted, the codes below error `array !== 0` does not execute and move to confirmation page.

```
if(isset($_POST['name_submit']))
       {
        if ($_POST)
        {
        // creating error array

        $errors_goods = array();

            // form validation

                if ($_POST['name_password']!== 6)
                    {
                        $goods_password_error = "*Please enter the correct answer to the security question.";
                        $errors_goods['password_error'] = $goods_password_error;
                    }

                if (empty($_POST['name_name']))
                    {
                        $goods_name_error = "*Please enter the name of the individual or organization looking for goods.";
                        $errors_goods['name_error'] = $goods_name_error;
                    }

                if (empty($_POST['name_goods']))
                    {
                        $goods_goods_error = "*Kind of good(s) e.g. Wheat or Artificial satellite.";
                        $errors_goods['goods_error'] = $goods_goods_error;

                    } 

                if (empty($_POST['name_quantity']))
                    {
                        $goods_quantity_error = "*Enter the quantity required.";
                        $errors_goods['quantity_error'] = $goods_quantity_error;
                    }

                if (empty($_POST['name_email']) && empty($_POST['name_phone']))
                    {
                        $goods_email_error = "*Email / We do not share or pass on your contact detail. OR";
                        $errors_goods['email_error'] = $goods_email_error;
                    }

                if (empty($_POST['name_email']) && empty($_POST['name_phone']))
                    {
                        $goods_phone_error = "*Please enter the phone number if wished to be contacted by phone.";
                        $errors_goods['phone_error'] = $goods_phone_error;
                    }



                    if (count($errors_goods) == 0) 
            {

                $to      = 'gill264@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'goods_goods';
                $message = 'Name: $goods_name \n requires goods_quantity of goods_goods. \n There contact details are:
                e-mail: goods_email \n Phone: goods_phone.';

                mail($to, $subject, $message);
header('Location:Message Confirmation.html');

            }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried please, we are not here to do your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(empty($errorArray) &&  (!empty($email) || !empty($phone))){
  //send email
}
```

Comment: If ya can check the above code please, something is slipping my eye, it does not work. Thanking you for your earlier reply.